# highstock chart can't display

Tags: highcharts

I made a highstock chart, but can't display data lines with 2 issue.
1. line can display only after click the legend "db2", but if click "db2" legend again both lines disappeared on same time.
2. if click on navigator bar, the lines can't display anymore.

I can't find errors when with more data in chart, have relation with dataset?

any response is appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/freedba/PE8w9/

```js
$(function() {

       chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
           chart : {
               renderTo : 'container',
               events: {
                   load: function(){
                   this.series[1].hide();
            }}
           },
           title : {
               text : 'CPU Usage'
           },
           rangeSelector : {
               inputEnabled: false,
               enabled : false
           },
           legend : {
               enabled : true,
               align: 'center',
               margin: 1,
               verticalAlign: 'top',
               y: 40
           },
           series : [{
                name: 'db1',
                data: [[1362329987000,66.392],[1362329987000,58.461],[1362333587000,69.202],[1362335387000,57.733],[1362337187000,64.396],[1362337187000,95.374],[1362340786000,70.336],[1362342587000,68.595],[1362342587000,57.584],[1362344386000,70.062],[1362346247000,57.603],[1362347987000,57.104],[1362351586000,58.707],[1362351586000,62.229],[1362353387000,66.306],[1362355186000,71.908],[1362356987000,75.329],[1362358787000,76.908],[1362360586000,78.672],[1362362387000,80.002],[1362366047000,76.953],[1362366047000,76.454],[1362367787000,77.292],[1362369587000,79.394],[1362371386000,79.407],[1362373187000,74.773],[1362376787000,73.813],[1362376787000,74.348],[1362380387000,80.611],[1362380387000,76.722],[1362383986000,74.372],[1362385787000,75.392],[1362385787000,77.195],[1362387587000,75.174],[1362389387000,76.475],[1362391187000,82.395],[1362392987000,73.701],[1362394787000,70.803],[1362396587000,68.749],[1362398387000,67.568],[1362400187000,69.154],[1362402047000,66.909],[1362403786000,76.237],[1362405587000,74.917],[1362407387000,65.742],[1362409187000,61.779],[1362410987000,60.812],[1362412786000,69.091],[1362416447000,64.922],[1362418187000,57.811],[1362418187000,66.428],[1362419986000,59.138],[1362423587000,56.253],[1362425387000,92.792],[1362427187000,78.373],[1362428987000,65.787],[1362430847000,63.182],[1362430847000,64.234],[1362432587000,64.637],[1362436186000,57.338],[1362437987000,59.004],[1362439787000,63.968],[1362439787000,67.604],[1362443387000,72.238],[1362443387000,74.873],[1362445187000,81.961],[1362447047000,82.649],[1362448786000,66.152],[1362452387000,57.261],[1362452387000,57.403],[1362454186000,55.278],[1362455987000,60.189],[1362457787000,63.292],[1362459587000,63.357]]
            },{
                name: 'db2',
                data: [[1362328192000,19.118],[1362329992000,18.965],[1362333592000,19.702],[1362335392000,18.79],[1362335392000,20.061],[1362338992000,23.215],[1362340792000,21.204],[1362340792000,18.421],[1362344391000,17.965],[1362344391000,18.741],[1362347992000,17.357],[1362347992000,18.137],[1362351592000,19.581],[1362353392000,21.412],[1362353392000,21.419],[1362355192000,28.231],[1362356991000,30.765],[1362358792000,32.987],[1362362391000,33.341],[1362362391000,32.515],[1362366052000,32.571],[1362366052000,31.088],[1362367792000,29.784],[1362369591000,29.558],[1362371391000,29.819],[1362374992000,30.587],[1362374992000,29.463],[1362376791000,30.728],[1362378592000,30.446],[1362380392000,30.851],[1362382191000,36.051],[1362383991000,35.441],[1362385792000,33.209],[1362387591000,31.225],[1362389392000,30.339],[1362391192000,34.573],[1362392991000,27.501],[1362394792000,26.62],[1362396592000,26.338],[1362398392000,25.419],[1362400192000,25.533],[1362402052000,21.722],[1362403791000,24.724],[1362405592000,27.066],[1362407392000,26.831],[1362410992000,22.171],[1362410992000,20.194],[1362414591000,18.257],[1362416392000,19.01],[1362418192000,19.03],[1362418192000,19.437],[1362421792000,18.887],[1362421792000,20.634],[1362425391000,23.431],[1362427192000,20.834],[1362428992000,18.702],[1362428992000,18.851],[1362432592000,18.274],[1362434391000,17.454],[1362436192000,18.367],[1362436192000,19.625],[1362437991000,21.239],[1362439792000,21.598],[1362441592000,28.303],[1362443392000,30.406],[1362445191000,32.64],[1362447052000,31.959],[1362450591000,33.007],[1362450591000,31.138],[1362452391000,31.826],[1362454192000,29.662],[1362455991000,28.68],[1362457792000,29.442],[1362459591000,29.61]]
            }]
       });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the `StockChart` constructor:

```
       xAxis: {
           ordinal: false
       },
```

I think since you have some data points with duplicate X values, the chart drawing fails without this.  I noticed some errors in the JS console when loading your page, related to "width" or "x" properties being NaN, presumably because somewhere the delta-X values are used as divisors or similar.

With the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/LULhg/

Comment: It works. Thank you very much.
Maybe my series x data does not have exact same value on both series.

Comment: confirmed there are missing data in x values which cause the error.